# Return SiteOrigin post carousel to first slide using a button

Tags: javascript, css, carousel

I am using a SiteOrigin post carousel to display all of my posts with thumbnails and post names. By clicking on "previous" and "next" arrows/chevrons I notice the left margin change accordingly.

`<ul class="sow-carousel-items" style="transition-duration: 0.45s; margin-left: -3900px;">`

I attempted to make a button with a function to return carousel at its first slide by changing the `margin-left` property to zero.

```
<button onclick="toCarouselStart()">Jump back to first slide</button>


<script>
function toCarouselStart(){
document.getElementsByClassName("sow-carousel-items").style.marginLeft="0px";
}
</script>
```

But when I click the button, the console shows an error:

> Cannot set property 'marginLeft' of undefined

What am I missing ?

I've been following [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_marginleft) method.